# Calling my representatives when I have out of state area code

Tags: united-states, legislative-process, lobbying

Like this [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1129/) comic, my US cell phone number is where I was living in 2006 which is not in my current state of residence. When I call my elected officials I often wonder if my call is being given less significance because it comes from out of their district. Is this a valid concern or are all calls treated equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When connecting the call, there is no order of priority; when the representatives office line picks up the call and sees it comes from an out of state area code, they may ask you for your ZIP code to determine if you've called the correct representative. Once they confirm that, then your call is treated equally to all other calls.